# Enquiry on dyadic decomposition and certain integrals

Tags: integration

Consider the integral

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$

Suppose that

1) $I$ is well defined;

2) $f$ is continuos on $(-\infty, \infty)$;

3) $g$ is not well-defined for infinitely many values on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

My question is: can a dyadic decomposition work for estimating $I$ ?

Comment: The integral is a convolution-in-disguise at the point 0 (if you flip either f(-x) or g(-x)). Convolution can be composed linearly with other convolutions (which for example dyadic decomposition by the wavelet transform is). I am not sure if it is in the same sense you are looking for, but maybe it can give some hints.

Comment: If g  is undefined (not well-defined)  on a countable set and you are able to estimate f and g where g is well defined, then I reckon you should be able to dyadically decompose around the points where g is not well-defined.